# How to specify adUnitId programmatically for AdMob?

Tags: android, admob, adview

I'm trying to set adUnitId programmatically to ads from the new Google Play services (old AdMob).

I have this in XML (used in an `<include>`):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

and this in onCreate():

```
AdView mAdview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdview.setAdUnitId(((App)getApplication()).getAdmobKey());

    mAdview.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            findViewById(R.id.adView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And I get:

> The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.

So the second option was to make the ad programmatically.

The new XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    />
```

The new code:

```
AdView mAdview = new AdView(this);
...
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView)).addView(mAdview);
mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But I get the same error.

I tried also to inherit from com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView to make a custom view, but it's final.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953075/how-to-create-an-admob-banner-programatically

Comment: I think that response is old. I haven't the constructor  AdView(<activity>, <baner_size>, <publisher_id>)

Comment: I have had same problem, same exception. Works only when adUnitId is in xml.

Comment: What does `getAdmobKey()` do?

Comment: Returns a string with the adUnitId

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The method `loadAd()` checks if `(mAdView.getAdSize() == null || mAdView.getAdUnitId() == null)` when loadAd happens.

Try logging the boolean output of `(mAdView.getAdSize() == null || mAdView.getAdUnitId() == null)` before calling loadAd to determine its state:

```
    mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();
    if(mAdView.getAdSize() != null || mAdView.getAdUnitId() != null)
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
   // else Log state of adsize/adunit
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView)).addView(mAdview);
```

Comment: What if I have ConstraintLayout, how to add AdView to the ConstraintLayout?

Comment: I solved. Solution with ConstraintLayout put below

Answer (score 1):

If you using `ConstraintLayout` or `CoordinatorLayout` solution here

For `ConstraintLayout`

```
private AdView mAdView;
private AdRequest mAdRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addAdView();
    initAd();
}

private void addAdView() {
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout);
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner1_id));

    mAdView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    constraintLayout.addView(mAdView);
    constraintSet.connect(mAdView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(mAdView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(mAdView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
    constraintSet.constrainHeight(mAdView.getId(), ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
    constraintSet.constrainWidth(mAdView.getId(), ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

}

private void initAd() {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
    });

    initBanner();

}

private void initBanner() {
    mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(mAdRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();

        }
    });
}
```

For `CoordinatorLayout`

```
private AdView mAdView;
private AdRequest mAdRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addAdView();
    initAd();
}

private void addAdView() {
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);

    mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner1_id));

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM;
    mAdView.setLayoutParams(params);

    mAdView.setId(View.generateViewId());

    coordinatorLayout.addView(mAdView);

}

private void initAd() {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
    });

    initBanner();

}

private void initBanner() {
    mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(mAdRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();

        }
    });
}
```