# Android : How to display Ad only using Java and not xml

Tags: java, android, admob

Is it possible to generate ad Banner using java coding in android eclipse, without using any xml `<com.google.....>` tags?

Comment: Yes create a view programmatically and assign the view to ad

Comment: have you any source code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24411058/2714340 check this to create a view

Comment: Also, Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24776339/2714340 and for customization have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of AdView and add to frame layout like,

```
AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
frameLayout.addView(mAdView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your **Activity**

```
//Add this in OnCreate of Activity to initialize the ad
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "< your-ad-unit-Id >");
```

```
//Add this wherever your code needs to add the ad

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Additionally to adjust the position to Bottom
layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

// Create a banner ad
mAdView = new AdView(this);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("<your-ad-unit-Id>");

// Create an ad request.
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

// Optionally populate the ad request builder.
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
layout.addView(mAdView);

// Start loading the ad.
mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

setContentView(layout);
```

---

Then check if you have given the permissions in **Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Add meta data below inside < application > in **Manifest**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

---

And finally check if you have added required **dependency** to compile in **app gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

---

---