# Creating Android xml Element with properties in Code

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, adview

I want to create an xml element in code on the fly, but only if it is not already there.

This is the xml of the element I want to create. **(Note, I will not be declaring this in xml, this is the xml of the element I want to create in code)**:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

Is this the correct check to see if it already there?

```
AdView adView;
if((adView = (AdView) m_Context.findViewById(R.id.adView)) != null){
    // It is already there
}else{
    // It is not there, create it on the fly
}
```

Also how do I add it to the bottom of a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Why do you need to check the view is there or not, if you specifically declare in xml

Comment: I am not declaring it in the xml. I want to create it in code. I am just showing the xml code to show what I want to create in code. I will make it clearer in the original question.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/15954373/2219208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to check the condition run-time you can directly create **on-the-fly**.

This is better way to add view on run-time based on condition

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

         AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
         mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
         mAdView.setAdUnitId("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");


         AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
         adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
         layout.addView(mAdView);
         mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
         setContentView(layout);
```

It's totally depends on your condition to customize the thing around.